# Using HTML5 CSS in Eclipse

Tags: css, eclipse, html, sapui5

I am beginner in SAPUI5. I am building SAPUI5 application with HTML5 in Eclipse. In index.html page I am creating a html5 page, I have created css folder under WebContent. In index.html I added  to refer css file. But properties in css are not affecting in html page. Do I need to add any other code to refer CSS file.

**Css:**

```
@CHARSET "ISO-8859-1";
body {
background-image: "image/splash-sunrise.jpg";
background-size: 100px 100px; 
background-repeat:no-repeat; 
}
```

Comment: can you post the part of the code where you refer the css file?

Comment: it would be better if you post some code here.

Comment: Within Head tag I referred like below <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/styles.css" />

Comment: Do you want to use CSS for a SAPUI5 Control or for the whole site?

Comment: Your CSS snippet is not complete either

Comment: When opening the developer console in your browser can you see whether your CSS file was loaded successfully?

Answer (score 1):

To use CSS within the SAPUI5 environment you should link your controls to a specific CSS class. You can do it like this:

```
var myButton = new sap.m.Button();
myButton.addStyleClass("myButtonStyle");
```

And your CSS could look like this:

```
@CHARSET "ISO-8859-1";

.myButtonStyle {
    color:#FFCCDD;
}
```

Make sure that you load the CSS file into your application, for example like this in your html file:

```
<link href="css/style.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />
```

Of course you can use this for your whole page as well. For your needs you could also take a look at the [App](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/sdk/#docs/api/symbols/sap.m.App.html) control which provides some utilities for background images if you´re using mobile controls.