# SAPUI5/OpenUI5: CSS for custom control?

Tags: sapui5

I am currently working on a custom control in SAPUI5/OpenUI5 and I am wondering how I can get the required CSS into the application.
Where would I place the CSS code specific for my control? And how do I load it then from the control?
I could not find anything in the documentation....

Thanks and best regards,
Daniel

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In [this](https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/#docs/guide/91f184586f4d1014b6dd926db0e91070.html) tutorial, it's described how to use CSS in the renderer of custom controls.

If you're not using a custom renderer, you can attach CSS like to any other control like described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23104560/1969374).

Always make sure that you load the CSS file e.g. in your html file.

**Edit:**

According to the comments [jQuery.sap.includeStyleSheet()](https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/api/jQuery.sap/methods/jQuery.sap.includeStyleSheet) solved it.

Comment: Not really. The first link (which I already came across earlier) demonstrates how to provide the CSS inline - generating the same CSS for each instance of the object. The second link does also not answer the question how to load the CSS. Putting or loading the CSS in the HTML file does also not seem to be the ideal solution since then the correct execution of the control would depend on the environment. The SAPUI5 library does also seem to load the required CSS files dynamically - but I could not yet figure out how....

Comment: Ok, I think I got your point now. You could try to call jQuery.sap.includeStyleSheet() from within your control. The function is described [here](https://sapui5.netweaver.ondemand.com/sdk/#docs/api/symbols/jQuery.sap.html):

Comment: Also, you can push your CSS to the theme if you declared your custom controls as a library.

Comment: True! Could you please post the link to the documentation, I don´t find it anymore.

Answer (score 2):

At the time of writing this, you require `sap/ui/dom/includeStylesheet` and call it within your `init` function.

Example:

```js
sap.ui.define(
    [
        'sap/ui/core/Control',
        'sap/ui/dom/includeStylesheet'
    ],
    function (Control, includeStylesheet) {
        'use strict';

        return Control.extend('Example.control.MyControl', {
            // some more boilerplate code

            init: function () {
                includeStylesheet('../css/mycontrol.css');
            }
        });
    }
);
```

Answer (score 1):

You should create all your custom controls in a control library with a theme. 
https://github.com/SAP/openui5/blob/master/docs/controllibraries.md

Loading the theme in the sapui5 bootstrap causes the load of the library.css file in your control library with the same theme name (e.g. "sap_bluecrystal").